# How to count the number of occurrences of a string given it also matches another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

So I have the following:

```
=SUM(LEN(Data!$J$2:$J$9999)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Data!$J$2:$J$9999,"dependent","")))/LEN("dependent")
```

Which given the range j2:j9999 will count the number of occurrences of the string dependent, regardless of the rest of the cells - ie if the cell contains primary,dependent and another is dependent the count would be 2.

What I need and cant really figure out is given the above how would i also reference another cell in the row. So if i still need to count the occurrences of the the string dependent, how would i limit that to just count the occurrences if both the string dependent was found and also another cell in the same row as the cell with dependent == foo.

EXAMPLE:

```
column1, column2, column3

foo, bar, dependent 
bar, baz, dependent
foo, bar, primary dependent dependent1
```

In this example i would like to do a pseudo countifs where i count the occurrences of the string dependent given the row also matches foo.

The count here would be 3 because row 1 has foo in cell1 and has dependent and row 3 has foo in column1 and 2 occurrences of dependent in column 3

Answer (score 1):

A version that doesn't require array-entry:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Data!$H$2:$H$9999="foo")*(LEN(Data!$J$2:$J$9999)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Data!$J$2:$J$9999,"dependent",""))))/LEN("dependent")
```

or, if the "dependent" will only occur once per cell, you could just use:

```
=COUNTIFS(Data!$H$2:$H$9999,"foo",Data!$J$2:$J$9999,"*dependent*")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully work. It's done based off your sample data, and returns the value in D1:

```
Sub StringCounter_II_The_Sequel()
Dim range1 As Range, rCell As Range
Dim string1 As String
Dim length As Long, i As Long
string1 = "dependent"
length = Len(string1)
     Set range1 = ActiveSheet.Range("C:C")
        For Each rCell In range1
            txt = rCell.Text
            If InStr(txt, string1) > 0 And rCell.Offset(,-2) = "foo" Then
                i = i + (Len(txt) - Len(Replace(txt, string1, ""))) / length
            End If
        Next rCell    
ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Value = i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `IF` to your formula, like this:

```
=SUM(IF(Data!H2:H9999="foo",LEN(Data!$J$2:$J$9999)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Data!$J$2:$J$9999,"dependent","")))/LEN("dependent"),0)
```

Obviously, it's still an array formula, entered with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd>